# What are the different uses of “non mais”?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot

Non mais oh, non mais c’est quoi, non mais allô quoi... just some examples, but how do I use it appropriately? It seems like there’s so many different nuances and I have trouble understanding them.

J’ai besoin d’aide, s’il vous plaît !

Answer (score 2):

« **Non mais oh !** » pourrait être appelé une locution interjective ; elle sert à exprimer plus qu'une forte désapprobation, c'est à dire qu'elle sert à faire remarquer le caractère outré d'un comportement, d'une remarque, d'une requête ; elle est faite en réplique à quelqu'un pour lui signifier le caractère extrême de leur acte ou elle est faite en parlant de ces actes à d'autres personnes ; elle appartient à la langue familière mais polie, en particulier la langue des femmes ;

- Vous me passez devant sans même me demander de vous céder mon tour et vous vous plaignez qu'on vous parle trop for en plus ! Non mais oh ! c'est à vous de faire attention à votre comportement !
- Il voulait que je le transporte à la gare en voiture avec ses bagages et une fois arrivé il fallait que je paye le porteur … Non mais oh! Tu vois comment il est ?

« **Non mais c'est quoi …** » est très similaire à la locution « Non mais oh » excepté qu'elle fait partie de la phrase ; la forme élégante de cette locution est « **non mais qu'est-ce que c'est …** » ; ces locutions servent à formuler des questions qui n'en sont pas et qui en fait expriment plus qu'une forte désapprobation ;

- Non mais qu'est-ce que c'est ces façons de parler ?
- Non mais qu'est-ce que c'est ces manières ?
- Non mais c'est quoi ce comportement mépris pour tout ce qui est dit avec seulement de la considération pour ce qu'on dit soi-même ?

Je pense qu'il n'est pas difficile d'utiliser ces locutions de manière appropriée mais à mon avis la première a un côté légèrement veule qui ne convient pas tout à fait à une expression masculine.

« **Non mais allô quoi** » n'est pas une unité de sens du langage, mais un assemblage libre dans lequel il n'y a pas de relation entre les mots ; possiblement, après avoir répondu « non » étant sur le point de formuler une objection, ou une réserve, ou autre chose, la personne n'entendantt plus très bien, elle enchaine avec « allô » et continue par « quoi », qui est la façon colloquiale de dire que l'on ne comprend pas ou que l'on n'entend pas.
À part cela c'est une [pseudo-expression](http://leplus.nouvelobs.com/contribution/819691-non-mais-allo-quoi-nabilla-ne-merite-pas-cette-exposition-mediatique.html)  que le monde des distraction populaires et les médias ont montée en épingle,  qui serait supposée communiquer de l'étonnement et que l'on ne dit pas au téléphone. le rapport avec le téléphone est d'ailleurs inexistant ; c'est n'importe quoi.